# What can I do about griefing in Spartan Ops?

Tags: halo-4

Recently I've been playing more Spartan Ops Matchmaking, because the experience gain is so much better.  However, I've run into a continuous stream of scumbags who shoot me in the back, plasma pistol or destroy my vehicle, and in one case - I shit you not - ***pinned me in a corner and humped me***.

In the past when Bungie was at the reigns, they employed the "banhammer" to dispense justice on folks of a particularly jerkish nature.  Is anything like this making a return for Halo 4?  If someone is hardcore griefing me in Spartan Ops, what are my options?

Comment: Man tell me about it.  I've played several rounds of Shootout in Valhalla and had people just blowing up everyone else's Mantises.  It's weird because Wargames will kick you from the match if someone steps in front of your rocket launcher once.

Comment: That was you I was humping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's old fashioned, but personally, I would just give negative reviews to the idiots that spoil the game. That way they become avoided players, and your chances of running into the douches in matchmaking again drops considerably. Also, that ruins the griefers rep. Not enough people fully utilize the review system because I see far too many trash-talkers & griefers who still have 5 stars.

Comment: After some review of [XBox policies](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/halo/halo-4-banning-and-enforcement#85cf752d8bea4ac5ab1540bea4e041a9), I think that is the thing to do.  I don't see any other way that "griefing" could cause automated bans - and this XBox article specifically mentions *Cheating or “griefing” (intentionally ruining the fun of the game for other players)* as something that can get you banned.  Moving the check for this reason.

Comment: @EBongo fair enough. The problem with XBL's review system is that it's almost impossible to lose rep - I don't think I've ever seen anyone with fewer than 5 stars, not matter how consistently bad their behaviour. I think every person from every game that they've ever played online would have to complain to get it below 3.

Comment: @Keith I agree that the system leaves much to be desired.  You start at 3 stars, but climb to 5 with only a few likes.  However, despite the star level - I see the reviews are the only automatic way to cause bans - which the XBox ban article states as a source of bans.  If they are banning for griefing, how else are they doing it?

Answer (score 2):

1. In Spartan Ops you get the XP regardless, so when this happens I just go AFK until the end of the match and then take my XP.
2. Have a plasma pistol and/or grenades in your loadout - both make short work of 'friendly' Mantis.
3. Meh, douchebags is kind of the point of Halo/MW/any big online game. The more popular the title the [more problems with behaviour it has](http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2004/03/19) (NSFW link).

Personally I think they've made some really weird friendly fire decisions in Spartan Ops - either it should be fully on or fully off. Why can I run someone down in the Ghost (usually by accident) but if I blow up their Mantis they're unhurt? It makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  All things I'd considered, but I hold out hope there is some sort of streamlined "punishment" of sorts which other AAA titles have featured.  For now I will just shake my fist with rage at the sky and nod solemnly in acceptance of Gabriel's GIF theory.  If I could give you +2 for that, I totally would.

Comment: @EBongo yeah, it should be easy to nominate and vote to kick jerks.

Comment: @Keith going afk is personally the thing i hate the most in spartan ops or co-op campaign. because of the stupid design of the networking mode for those game types, going afk makes everyone else lag because the host only sends out information to refresh the server once input has been received for all other players in the game. i can deal with people shooting my vehicle in spartan ops, it is when someone goes afk and the game becomes almost unplayable due to lag that i wish there was a boot option

Comment: @Alex - er, so some griefing ass blocks me in a corner but I'm supposed to make sure that I keep moving so that _he_ doesn't experience any lag? Note that we're not taking about the occasional idiot shooting your vehicle, we're talking about when some 'tard blocks you in a corner _for the entire round._ If your team mates don't help you out from under the griefer maybe they deserve the lag too.